# Create aggregate df out of webscraping multiple pages using Rvest and Glue

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm working on scraping data from a table on the following website

```
https://fantasy.nfl.com/research/scoringleaders?position=1&statCategory=stats&statSeason=2019&statType=weekStats&statWeek=1
```

I want to create a scrape that takes all 17 weeks, all four positions (qb,rb,wr,te) and takes the first 4 pages to get the first 100 rows (only 25 shown on a page at a time).

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(rvest) 
library(glue) 

scrape_19 <- function(week, position, page) {

    Sys.sleep(3)  

    cat(".")

    url <- glue("https://fantasy.nfl.com/research/scoringleaders?{page}position={position}&sort=pts&statCategory=stats&statSeason=2019&statType=weekStats&statWeek={week}")


read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>%  
  html_table(header = T) %>%
  simplify() %>% 
  first() %>% 
  setNames(paste0(colnames(.), as.character(.[1,]))) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  list()
}
```

Here are all the iterations of each call in glue:

```
week = 1:17;
position = 1:4;
page = c("", "offset=26&", "offset=51&", "offset=76&")
```

The problem I run into is when I try to make one df with all the data for each week, position and page. Here is code that works for week and position but will not work for an additional nested df.

```
scaffold <- tibble(week = weeks,
                   position = list(positions)) %>% tidyr::unnest()
scaffold

tbl_data <- scaffold %>% 
            mutate(data = purrr::map2(week, position, ~scrape_19(.x, .y)[[1]]))
```

Basically, I need help in crafting the scaffold and turning that scaffold into the final total data set with all weeks, positions and pages.

Comment: @akrun here is what I was trying to describe.

Comment: You sure seem to like to ask questions about scraping this website. It would be helpful if you tried to make your questions as clear as possible with the desired output so possible solutions can be tested and verified to work and solve your problem. Does this one really even involve the scrapring part? Are you just trying to build a list of strings (urls) with some combination of variables? Try to focus only on one specific problem at a time. Take away anything not directly related to the problem.

Comment: @MrFlick well I do apologize as I was doing my best to be clear. Yes, I am trying to learn scraping with rvest and glue and I was just trying to be as detailed as possible so people might know what I'm trying to get at. At the end of the day, the desired output is a single df w the first 100 rows (only 25 rows are shown on page at a time on website) for all four positions (qb, rb, wr, te) across all 17 weeks of 2019.

Comment: Two misspellings (and a warning) so far; 'week' != 'weeks' and 'position' != 'positions' . Appears scaffold is just an `expand.grid` of those two. And finally an error message that appears to indicate the website is expecting a value for `{page}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt. I am not sure if `glue()` is the way to go. See below.

```
first_name <- c("Fred", "Ana", "Bob")
last_name <- c("JOhnson", "Trump")
glue('My name is {first_name} {last_name}.')
```

> Error: Variables must be length 1 or 3

Your case is similar to this example. So I tried to create all possible links using loops with `map()`. Then, I checked if all URLs exist or not. I used `map_dfr()` in order to loop through all URLs and bind all data frames. In this process, I added week and position information as well. If position is 1, it is QB. If necessary, replace these numbers by yourself. Note that I scraped four URLs in this demonstration.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

# Create all URLs.

# Create 4 base URLs
paste("https://fantasy.nfl.com/research/scoringleaders?",
      c("", "offset=26&", "offset=51&", "offset=76&"),
      "position={position}&sort=pts&statCategory=stats&statSeason=2019&statType=weekStats&statWeek={week}",
      sep = "") -> mytemp

# For each base URL, create 4 URLs. (4 x 4 = 16 URLs)
map(.x = 1:4,
    .f = function(x){gsub(x = mytemp, pattern = "\\{position\\}", replacement = x)}) %>% 
unlist -> mytemp

# For each of the 16 URLs, create 17 URLs
map(.x = 1:17,
    .f = function(x){gsub(x = mytemp, pattern = "\\{week\\}", replacement = x)}) %>% 
unlist -> myurls


# Check if any URLs are invalid
sapply(myurls, url_success) %>% table

# TRUE 
#  272 

# Scrape the tables
map_dfr(.x = myurls[1:4],
        .f = function(x){read_html(x) %>% 
                         html_nodes("table") %>% 
                         html_table() %>% 
                         simplify() %>% 
                         first() %>% 
                         setNames(paste0(colnames(.), as.character(.[1,]))) %>% 
                         slice(-1) %>% 
                         mutate(position = str_extract(string = x, pattern = "(?<=position=)\\d+(?=&)"),
                                week = str_extract(string = x, pattern = "(?<=statWeek=)\\d+"))},
        .id = "url") -> foo


   url Rank                               Player  Opp PassingYds PassingTD PassingInt RushingYds RushingTD ReceivingRec ReceivingYds
1    1    1               Lamar Jackson QB - BAL @MIA        324         5          -          6         -            -            -
2    1    2                Dak Prescott QB - DAL  NYG        405         4          -         12         -            -            -
3    1    3              Deshaun Watson QB - HOU  @NO        268         3          1         40         1            -            -
4    1    4            Matthew Stafford QB - DET @ARI        385         3          -         22         -            -            -
5    1    5              Patrick Mahomes QB - KC @JAX        378         3          -          2         -            -            -

   ReceivingTD RetTD MiscFumTD Misc2PT FumLost FantasyPoints position week
1            -     -         -       -       -         33.56        1    1
2            -     -         -       -       -         33.40        1    1
3            -     -         -       -       -         30.72        1    1
4            -     -         -       -       1         27.60        1    1
5            -     -         -       -       -         27.32        1    1
```

Comment: this is super helpful. I'm going to need to go back and reverse engineer what you did to better my understanding but I ran it with the first 4 urls as you wrote in the code and then did it again with the first 40 to spot check and it looks very well done! Since I'm new to scraping and really just wanting to learn, should I focus on learning this httr package? also any further recommendations for scraping? Thank you so very much!  edit ps. is there a way to throw a Sys.sleep call in this to be courteous to host site?

Comment: @JeffHenderson You are welcome. You can add `Sys.sleep(3)` at the beginning of the custom function, for example. `Sys.sleep(3); read_html(x) %>%...` I guess scraping is something you can learn by going through anything you wanna try.

Comment: I had no idea you could throw a ; in a function as a separator. wow.learning so much! thank you much!